# Creating new column in dataframe based on conditions in 2 other columns

Tags: dataset, pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe

I would like to create a new column in my dataframe based on values from both the gender and `experimental_grouping` columns.

As I have it written below, the column `df['group_gender']` has `'control_m'` in every row.

Any ideas on why the if statement isn't working/a better way to accomplish this goal?

```py
def group_and_gender(group):
    for i in group:
        if i == 'Controls':
            for i in df['gender']:
                if i == 'M':
                    df['group_gender'] = 'control_m'
                else: 
                    df['group_gender'] = 'control_f'
        else:
            for i in df['gender']:
                if i == 'M':
                    df['group_gender'] = 'dp_m'
                else: 
                    df['group_gender'] = 'dp_f'

group(df['experimental_grouping'])
```

Comment: Please ask programming questions on https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Is everything fine? Is it working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-the problem with an inaccurate filling of column `group_gender` is that in **df['group_gender'] = 'dp_m'** in the following code, if **i == 'M'** you are filling the whole column with **dp_m**, instead you should use methods like **iloc** but it is not really an efficient way specifically when having a large dataset. In following, I have provided a better way.

```py
for i in df['gender']:
    if i == 'M':
        df['group_gender'] = 'dp_m'
            else: 
        df['group_gender'] = 'dp_f'
```

**The more appropriate way**

```py
#creating an instant dataframe
import pandas as pd
d = {'gender':['M','M','F', 'M', 'F','M']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#filling the 'group_gender' column
df.loc[df['gender'] == 'M', 'group_gender'] = 'dp_m'
df.loc[df['gender'] == 'F', 'group_gender'] = 'dp_f'
```

**-You are not filling in `experimental_gropuping` and returning the column:**

```
group(df['experimental_grouping'])
```

**-What is this group? (Can you provide more details about the first part of your code?)**